# Cast array dict into json

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, find

My problem is that `json.dumps(res)` failed and I don't know why.
If you know how to parse this result to JSON, let me know :)

```
def transactionModel(filters):
    arrayFilters = []
    for key, value in filters.items():
        if (str(value) != ""):
            arrayFilters.append({key: value})
    query = { "$and": arrayFilters }
    cursor = dataTable.find(query, mandatoryFileds)
    res = []
    for doc in cursor:
        res.append(doc)
    response = json.dumps(res)
    print('this is the response', response)
    return "toto"
```

The res array looks like :

```
[{
  '_id': ObjectId('6151837040e318df5bfb25e9'),
  'id_mutation': '2020-2',
  'date_mutation': '2020-01-02',
  'valeur_fonciere': 2175,
  'adresse_numero': '',
  'adresse_nom_voie': 'TERRES DES CINQ SAULES',
  'code_postal': 1290,
  'nom_commune': 'Laiz',
  'lot1_surface_carrez': '',
  'type_local': '',
  'nombre_pieces_principales': '',
  'surface_terrain': 85,
  'longitude': 4.893436,
  'latitude': 46.251868
}, {
  '_id': ObjectId('6151837040e318df5bfb25ea'),
  'id_mutation': '2020-2',
  'date_mutation': '2020-01-02',
  'valeur_fonciere': 2175,
  'adresse_numero': '',
  'adresse_nom_voie': 'TERRES DES CINQ SAULES',
  'code_postal': 1290,
  'nom_commune': 'Laiz',
  'lot1_surface_carrez': '',
  'type_local': '',
  'nombre_pieces_principales': '',
  'surface_terrain': 1148,
  'longitude': 4.894688,
  'latitude': 46.25182
}, {
  '_id': ObjectId('6151837040e318df5bfb25ee'),
  'id_mutation': '2020-2',
  'date_mutation': '2020-01-02',
  'valeur_fonciere': 2175,
  'adresse_numero': '',
  'adresse_nom_voie': 'TERRES DES CINQ SAULES',
  'code_postal': 1290,
  'nom_commune': 'Laiz',
  'lot1_surface_carrez': '',
  'type_local': '',
  'nombre_pieces_principales': '',
  'surface_terrain': 2960,
  'longitude': 4.894607,
  'latitude': 46.251943
}, {
  '_id': ObjectId('6151837140e318df5bfb371b'),
  'id_mutation': '2020-1741',
  'date_mutation': '2020-07-17',
  'valeur_fonciere': 506750,
  'adresse_numero': '',
  'adresse_nom_voie': 'TERRES DES CINQ SAULES',
  'code_postal': 1290,
  'nom_commune': 'Laiz',
  'lot1_surface_carrez': '',
  'type_local': '',
  'nombre_pieces_principales': '',
  'surface_terrain': 2,
  'longitude': 4.893256,
  'latitude': 46.247137
}, {
  '_id': ObjectId('6151837140e318df5bfb371c'),
  'id_mutation': '2020-1741',
  'date_mutation': '2020-07-17',
  'valeur_fonciere': 506750,
  'adresse_numero': '',
  'adresse_nom_voie': 'TERRES DES CINQ SAULES',
  'code_postal': 1290,
  'nom_commune': 'Laiz',
  'lot1_surface_carrez': '',
  'type_local': '',
  'nombre_pieces_principales': '',
  'surface_terrain': 341,
  'longitude': 4.892975,
  'latitude': 46.247527
}, {
  '_id': ObjectId('6151837140e318df5bfb371d'),
  'id_mutation': '2020-1741',
  'date_mutation': '2020-07-17',
  'valeur_fonciere': 506750,
  'adresse_numero': '',
  'adresse_nom_voie': 'TERRES DES CINQ SAULES',
  'code_postal': 1290,
  'nom_commune': 'Laiz',
  'lot1_surface_carrez': '',
  'type_local': '',
  'nombre_pieces_principales': '',
  'surface_terrain': 1,
  'longitude': 4.893024,
  'latitude': 46.24725
}, {
  '_id': ObjectId('6151837140e318df5bfb371e'),
  'id_mutation': '2020-1741',
  'date_mutation': '2020-07-17',
  'valeur_fonciere': 506750,
  'adresse_numero': '',
  'adresse_nom_voie': 'TERRES DES CINQ SAULES',
  'code_postal': 1290,
  'nom_commune': 'Laiz',
  'lot1_surface_carrez': '',
  'type_local': '',
  'nombre_pieces_principales': '',
  'surface_terrain': 7,
  'longitude': 4.892973,
  'latitude': 46.247273
}, {
  '_id': ObjectId('6151837140e318df5bfb371f'),
  'id_mutation': '2020-1741',
  'date_mutation': '2020-07-17',
  'valeur_fonciere': 506750,
  'adresse_numero': '',
  'adresse_nom_voie': 'TERRES DES CINQ SAULES',
  'code_postal': 1290,
  'nom_commune': 'Laiz',
  'lot1_surface_carrez': '',
  'type_local': '',
  'nombre_pieces_principales': '',
  'surface_terrain': 33,
  'longitude': 4.892961,
  'latitude': 46.247771
}, {
  '_id': ObjectId('6151837140e318df5bfb3720'),
  'id_mutation': '2020-1741',
  'date_mutation': '2020-07-17',
  'valeur_fonciere': 506750,
  'adresse_numero': '',
  'adresse_nom_voie': 'TERRES DES CINQ SAULES',
  'code_postal': 1290,
  'nom_commune': 'Laiz',
  'lot1_surface_carrez': '',
  'type_local': '',
  'nombre_pieces_principales': '',
  'surface_terrain': 1278,
  'longitude': '',
  'latitude': ''
}]
```

Comment: `[{'_id': ObjectId('6151837040e318df5bfb25e9')` this inside your json is causing the issue and its present on multiple location in your json file .

Comment: thank you it's working !!!

Comment: Define ObjectId('6151837040e318df5bfb25e9') and another ObjectId('X') correctly